# Stuck trying to understand N Choose K formula

Tags: combinatorics

I had a very simple question. I was looking at a problem recently, that dealt with a simple question. How many different ways can you get exactly 3 heads in 8 flips of the coin. I understand how to solve this question, there's $2^8$ total outcomes, and then we need figure out how many different subsets of those outcomes have 3 heads in them.

We do so by using $8 \choose 3$ however this is what I don't understand. My understanding of the $N\choose K$ formula is that, it gives us the number of subsets consisting of K elements that we can draw from a set of N elements.

In the case of our coin example, this would mean (to me) how many 3 element subsets can we choose from a set of 8 elements? However, this is simply not what we are looking for. For instance: the subset HHHTTTTT is not 3 elements long, it consists of 8 elements. The way I read $8 \choose 3$ to me it says: we have 8 elements, how many different ways can we select 3? But in the coin problem we are trying to figure out, how many different arrangements of those 3 elements exist shuffled around a subset that is 8 elements long, not 3.

I'm very confused, can someone please explain to me what I am misunderstanding?

Answer (score 4):

Think of it this way:  you have eight little coin holders.  Every time you flip a coin, you put that coin into one of those holders, showing either heads or tails.  If you want to get exactly 3 heads, then you have to fill exactly 3 of those little holders with coins showing heads.  Thus you are *choosing* 3 of the 8 holders (i.e. 8 choose 3) to have heads.  This completely determines the sequence of 8 coin tosses, since the rest must all be tails, thus we don't really have to worry too much about what is going on with the remaining 5 coin holders.